# How to use tokens as watermark on images

Tags: 7, media

I need to create a watermark on images in my website. The watermark should contain a text which consists of the node ID and its author ID.

So for every image a unique watermark is created. How can I do that?

I tried the following modules so far but I am not sure if they can do what I need:

1. [Imagecache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions)
2. [ImageMagick](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagemagick)
3. [textimage](https://www.drupal.org/project/textimage)
4. [IMCE Watermark](https://www.drupal.org/project/imce_watermark)
5. [Media watermark](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_watermark)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Imagecache Actions can do what you want. Text Overlay watermarking comes default in this module. I haven't checked if it supports tokens but you'll notice it immediately if it does. Don't forget to enable the tokens module.

Comment: There is no **Text Overlay** effect

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention you also need to enable the **Image Text Effects** module. Then, an image effect **Text** becomes available and I just tested it: it supports tokens.

Comment: What is the name of the **Image Text Effects** module? there is no module with the name **Image Text Effects**

Comment: It comes with the imagecache_actions module, all you have to do is enable it. The actual name is **Image Effects Text**.

Comment: I need to set the font size based on the image size, or make it relative. Is there any preprocess function or anything else to do this?

Comment: That's a tough one. You could try to override the general [image style theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) function and do some checks in there, but in image_effects_text.inc there is also a function [image_toolkit_invoke](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!image.inc/function/image_toolkit_invoke/7) which can be implemented in your own module (I think).